# Dar formato moneda a columna en Gridview con AutoGenerateColumns=true

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webforms, gridview

[image: Tengo esta tabla dinámica pero no logro dar el formato de divisa, para que sea separados por comas y tenga signo de pesos]

Tengo esta tabla dinámica pero no logro dar el formato de divisa, para que sea separados por comas y tenga signo de pesos
necesito que el formato sea desde el backend y no desde base de datos

Comment: Fijate si le podes dar formato así: `periodoSeguro.Columns("SeguroInicial").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"`

Answer (score 0):

Al utilizar la propiedad [AutoGenerateColumns
=true](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.8) se generan columnas automáticamente enlazadas a los datos. Y si quieres darle "formato personalizado" tienes varias opciones...
Pero ten en cuenta que si tienes pocos campos es conveniente describir la lista de columnas tu mismo (y no autogenerada), que es más sencillo de escribir y mentener que estar con AutoGenerateColumns y haciendo estas opciones que comento mas abajo. Así que dale una mirada a las opciones y recomendaciones en base a tu cantidad de columnas.

Genere un ejemplo que lo puedes ver aquí con los ejemplos

- https://github.com/fernandezja/aspnet-webforms-experiments y alli en la parte de [Gridview](https://github.com/fernandezja/aspnet-webforms-experiments/tree/master/src/WebApplication1/Gridview)

Las opciones que tienes que recuerdo que puedes hacer:

- OPCION 1: Enlazar directamente a un lista de objetos que tengan el campo formateado (pre-formatear con propiedades)
- OPCION 2: Enlazar directamente DataTable (o mapear desde una lista) y manipulas los valores (idem al anterior)
- OPCION 3: En el evento [OnRowDataBound](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound?view=netframework-4.8)
- OPCION 4 (Recomendación en este ejemplo particular): Columnas enlazadas manualmente (y AutoGenerateColumns=false)

**OPCION 1: Enlazar directamente a un lista de objetos que tengan el campo formateado (pre-formatear con propiedades)**
Aqui la idea es que en tus propiedades ya esten preformateadas. Puedes incluso crear objetos DTO (o ViewModels) que te ayuden a tener las propiedades que necesites solamente para dicha vista (no es necesario que sea las que vienen directamente de la fuente de datos). Asi solo bindeas/enlazas y ya se visualizara correctamente

Ejemplo de un objeto con una propiedad, pero puedes tener algo asi con las propiedades "listas para utilizar"

```
public class SeguroPeriodoViewModel
{
    private double _periodo1 = 0.0;
    
    public SeguroPeriodoViewModel(double periodo1)
    {
        _periodo1 = periodo1;
    }
    
    public string Periodo1Formateado
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("${0:C3}", _periodo1);
        }
    }
}
```

y luego enlazas o armas este listado en base a tus objetos de la fuente de datos y ya puedes mapearlo directamente

** - OPCION 2: Enlazar directamente DataTable (o mapear desde una lista) y manipulas los valores (idem al anterior)
**
Si bien la opcion 1, es con objetos generalmente tenemos esto en la capa web para visualizar, estas mapeando con DataTable bueno aquí lo mismo, pero en DataTable puedes "manipular" el contenido de cada celda (dependiendo de como la generaste)
En el ejemplo que envio, convierto a DataTable el mismo listado de objetos solo para ejemplificar y formatear la columna 4

```
var jedis = jediBusiness.List();
var jedisDataTable = jedis.ToDataTable();

foreach (DataRow row in jedisDataTable.Rows)
{
    var power = double.Parse(row["Power"].ToString());
    row[4] = $"{power.ToString("0.#00")}% <strong>Custom</strong>";
}

GridView2.DataSource = jedisDataTable;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

**OPCION 3: En el evento [OnRowDataBound](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound?view=netframework-4.8)**
Aquí ya no hay que manipular la fuente del dato sino el enlace de cada fila del gridview en dicho evento. Es util y deberias capturar el dato que viene enlazado (mira como recorremos solamente cuando se enlaza a DataRow porque tienes incluso encabezados etc)

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Option 3: RowDataBound
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var jedi = (Jedi)e.Row.DataItem;
        
        //Cell 4
        e.Row.Cells[4].Text = $"{jedi.Power.ToString("0.#00")}% <strong>Custom</strong>";
        
    }
}
```

**OPCION 4 (Recomendación en este ejemplo particular): Columnas enlazadas manualmente (y AutoGenerateColumns=false)**
Mirando la cantidad de columnas que tienes para enlazar no creo que se justifique las otras opciones pudiendo tu mismo generar cada columna para el mapeo. Por ejemplo te puede quedar asi

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de definir 2 columnas con tipo TemplateField definiendo el encabezado y item de como visualizar en modo "normal" (sin modo edicion,etc). Pero repite esto para cada columna

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false">
     <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                 <strong>Seguro Inicial</strong>
             </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("SeguroInicial", "{0:C2}")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>    
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                 <strong>Periodo 2</strong>
             </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("Periodo2", "{0:C2}")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>    
     </Columns>         
 </asp:GridView>
```

NOTA: Para darle formato debes utilizar un especificador de formato "{0:C2}" (por ejemplo para dos decimales en formato moneda) [Cadenas con formato numérico estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) especificamente [Especificador de formato de moneda (C)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#CFormatString)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.